# In fabric.js can we make an iText element editable with fixed position (unmovable)?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I have fabric.js latest version with an iText element to place on a specific coordinate, where I want to be able to just change/edit the text but not change its current position. Its position should be fixed and should not be stretched or skewed.

Here is my js code:

```
var text = new fabric.IText(textValue, {
    left: event.clientX - fabricObj.upperCanvasEl.getBoundingClientRect().left,
    top: event.clientY - fabricObj.upperCanvasEl.getBoundingClientRect().top,
    fill: inst.color,
    fontSize: inst.font_size,
    selectable: false
});
fabricObj.add(text);
```

Is there any property like movable which can be set to false or any other way?

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this.

```
var text = new fabric.IText(textValue, {
    left: event.clientX - fabricObj.upperCanvasEl.getBoundingClientRect().left,
    top: event.clientY - fabricObj.upperCanvasEl.getBoundingClientRect().top,
    fill: inst.color,
    fontSize: inst.font_size,
    lockMovementX: true,
    lockMovementY: true,
    lockScalingX: true,
    lockScalingY: true,
});
fabricObj.add(text);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer my friend, what If I have already added the element then I am loading this object can I set these properties later? using something like text.set() method?

Comment: Yes you can use text.set()

Comment: I tried to use text.set but nothing is happening.

Comment: Did you tried like this? text.set({ lockMovementX: true, lockMovementY: true})

Comment: For fabric which version you use?

Comment: @MeetGoyani I am using fabricjs version 4.3.1, I tried the method you mentioned in the answer but I am loading the text object on canvas dynamically after saving previous values in the database, but I want one user to be able to move that text and other user not move the text. How to insert lockMovementX dynamically in a fabricObject?